# Why do I get null when I don't include the foreign key column in my query? [laravel]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, GrantProposals and GrantProposalPdf. GrantProposals hasOne GrantProposalPdf. The foreign key column on GrantProposalPdf is `grant_proposal_id`. I only need the `file_dir` column from GrantProposalPdf so I use the following query:

```
    $grant_proposals = GrantProposals::with('grant_proposal_pdf:file_dir')
    ->select(
        'grant_proposals.id',
        'grant_proposals.reviewer_member_id',
        'grant_proposals.proposal_status',
        'grant_proposals.proposal_title',
        'grant_proposals.complete_address',
        'grant_proposals.contact_person_name',
        'grant_proposals.contact_person_position',
        'grant_proposals.contact_person_tel_no',
        'grant_proposals.contact_person_mobile_no',
        'grant_proposals.contact_person_mailing_add',
        'grant_proposals.contact_person_email',
        'grant_proposals.created_at',
        'grant_proposals.updated_at'
    )
        ->where($where)
        ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
        ->get();
```

But I will get null on my `grant_proposal_pdf`:

[image]

If I include the foreign key column:

```
        $grant_proposals = GrantProposals::with('grant_proposal_pdf:grant_proposal_id,file_dir')
        ->select(
            'grant_proposals.id',
            'grant_proposals.reviewer_member_id',
            'grant_proposals.proposal_status',
            'grant_proposals.proposal_title',
            'grant_proposals.complete_address',
            'grant_proposals.contact_person_name',
            'grant_proposals.contact_person_position',
            'grant_proposals.contact_person_tel_no',
            'grant_proposals.contact_person_mobile_no',
            'grant_proposals.contact_person_mailing_add',
            'grant_proposals.contact_person_email',
            'grant_proposals.created_at',
            'grant_proposals.updated_at'
        )
            ->where($where)
            ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
            ->get();
```

I get results:

[image]

GrantProposals Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class GrantProposals extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'grant_proposals';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'pdo_id',
        'name',
        'complete_address',
        'sec_registration_number',
        'pdo_mission',
        'pdo_vision',
        'pdo_history',
        'proposal_advocacy',
        'proposal_program',
        'proposal_title',
        'proposal_advocacy_title',
        'proposal_start_date',
        'proposal_end_date',
        'objective_of_the_program',
        'target_beneficiaries',
        'specific_problem_to_solve',
        'solutions_impact',
        'solutions_outcome',
        'solutions_output',
        'solutions_activity',
        'other_funding_source',
        'monitoring_processes_and_tools',
        'evaluation_method',
        'why_the_program_should_be_supported',
        'sustainability_of_the_project',
        'cover_letter',
        'budget_info',
        'solutions_info',
        'pdo_member_id',
        'proposal_status',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
    
    public function grant_proposal_addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GrantProposalAddresses::class, 'grant_proposal_id');
    }

    public function grant_proposal_bank_accounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GrantProposalBankAccounts::class, 'grant_proposal_id');
    }

    public function grant_proposal_images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GrantProposalImages::class, 'grant_proposal_id');
    }

    public function grant_proposal_locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GrantProposalLocations::class, 'grant_proposal_id');
    }

    public function grant_proposal_budgets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GrantProposalBudgets::class, 'grant_proposal_id');
    }

    public function grant_proposal_contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GrantProposalContacts::class, 'grant_proposal_id');
    }

    public function grant_proposal_geographic_areas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GrantProposalGeographicAreas::class, 'grant_proposal_id');
    }

    public function grant_proposal_pdf()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(GrantProposalPdf::class, 'grant_proposal_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Is this a bug or is this how it works on Laravel Eloquent?

Comment: It's in their docs that you must declare the foreign key https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

Comment: Any SQL query must include the foreign key as otherwise there is no link. You can inspect what is actually happening under the hood with `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` if you want to see what is actually getting queried on the SQL side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Laravel works. You need to include foreign key columns if you want to get proper relationship, otherwise you might get effects like this - you will get null although there is related record in database.

As mentioned in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns) to avoid such issues you need to include primary key and foreign key in listed columns to avoid unexpected errors like this.